# Convert a POCO to json using only certain fields

Tags: c#, json, razor

I have an object, `Project`, that contains many fields, some complex some not. It is an EF class, so I can't edit it to add attributes.

I just want to generate a JSON object containing 2 of the fields (one int (id) and one string (name))

I'd hate to create another ViewModel just for this...

In my viewmodel I have a `List<Project>`. Is there a way to use HTML helpers to get a JSON representation of *only* the properties I choose without using attributes?

Here is an example of the `Project` class:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id {get; set; } <-- Serialize this
    public string Name { get; set; } <-- Serialize this
    public Object AnotherObject [ Get; Set; } <-- Ignore this
    ....
}
```

I'd like it to become:

```
[{"id":"27","name":"test1"},{"id":"34","name":"test2"},{"id":"35","name":"test3"}]
```

The ultimate goal here to is output the json directly to the view as a `var` so that it can be used in building a JsGrid.

If there is a way to do it with Html helpers, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Json.NET has a great built in [ignore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) feature. If you tag the Property you want to exclude with the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, the serializer will not serialize that property.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public bool IsValid { get; set; }
```

Comment: Also note that if you decorate the class with `[DataContract]` or `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`, you can get it the other way around - so that properties are only serialized if you decorate them with `[JsonProperty]` or `[DataMember]`

Comment: I am aware of that feature. In my question I specifically stated that using attributes is not possible as the class is an EF class and I want to avoid creating a viewmodel just for one class.

Comment: Well you can use the attribute decorations in your EF models, assuming that you have Json.NET in that assembly, but that isn't a very good option.  Unless you want to write some custom Reflection routines, I would just make a view model.  That would be the SOLID way to do it. (entity for data access, view model for display in the UI)

Comment: Yeah.. I guess your right. I'll make a viewmodel for each class and just re-use them later if I need. Using EF is nice, but it also trips you up when trying to do other things...

Comment: EF can be a blessing and a curse.  Its usually a good rule to keep the EF POCOs as strict representations of your data and only use it with database access.  Since your DB tables are probably not 1 to 1 representations of what your UI displays, view models or DTOs are encouraged and inevitable.

Comment: As someone who REALLY believes in DRY (don't repeat yourself), the whole concept of models, view models, DB models, entities, etc drives me absolutely up the wall. I am constantly searching for ways to re-use what I have and the answer is almost always to re-write it in a *slightly* different way...

Comment: I think DRY is an important principle, but if you take it too literally you can potentially run into design flaws. Your models (although similar in the data they contain) serve different purposes.  Your EF models have virtual properties, your view model has the JsonIgnore attribute. I would argue that you aren't repeating yourself because functionally these are different things. I think DRY applies more to code where you have methods/routines that constantly apply logic to a string and return it, or convert a type to another, etc. If you do that in more than one place than DRY comes into play.